# Cant get value of input ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic3

I have simple input

```
<input type="number" maxlength=1 id="1"/>
```

and simple js in my .ts file

```
console.log(document.getElementById("1").value);
```

but i get an error

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

Comment: @MohamedAbbas its just for example

Comment: its wrong, use cordova only, because   since you do not want to use the Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all you should avoid accessing the DOM directly in Angular and subsequently in Ionic this is bad for performance and makes your code less maintainable.

Instead you add a `ngModel` to your input element:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="myInput"></ion-input>
```

And add an instance variable to your `.ts` file:

```
public myInput;
```

Your `ngModel` variable will have the value of your input field. You can log the changes to it by for example adding the `ionChange` event listener to your input:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="myInput" (ionInput)="logChange($event)"></ion-input>
```

And in your `.ts` file you add the method for it:

```
logChange(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: I had 4 inputs, and when i click button i should take all of them

Comment: Then you have to add a `ngModel` to every one and on click of your button you can just use the variables you defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to the HTMLInputElement ([HtmlInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)). This is because regular HTMLElements dont have value attribute.

```
console.log(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("1").value);
```

P.S. Given you are using Ionic 3 I assume you are also using Angular and there are better ways of grabbing dom elements such as [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

Comment: in a component class you can create a variable `val :HTMLInputElement;` but you may need to import the HTMLInputElement class.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given the `value` attribute the input `number`, you are getting undefined.

Either define the attribute in your element or extract it when a event happens.

```html
<input type="number" maxlength=1 id="1" />

<button onclick="bclick()">Click</button>

<script>

function bclick(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("1").value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know that this code working in browser. But in my ionic app its not working(. Code is calling on button submit.